# confusion about square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand by convention ,if  $\sqrt{x^2}=a$ , a is defined to be the positive root of x or the principal square root. but what does this mean for exponential equations- does $x^{0.5}=-5$ have no solutions?

Comment: In any situation where the inverse of a function has, or may have, multiple values you need to specify which one you are choosing.  You can, for example, allow complex solutions to your example but then there are two possibilities and if you want to work with a single number you'll have to specify which one you want.  Keep in mind that the choice you make for one value in the image may not be readily compatible with the choice you make for another value.

Comment: there is no real solution of the equation $x^{0.5}=-5$

Comment: Is this $x^{5}= -5$ or $x^{0.5} = -5$?

Comment: @WarrenHill made an edit to get rid of the confusion. It is $\frac{1}{2}$ (the edit is being peer-reviewed)

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted the example.  Yes...if you define $x^{0.5}$ as positive or non-existant then there are no cases wherein it equals -5.

Comment: okay, just to double check: the problem arises as x^0.5 is defined  as positive or non-existant?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner There is no solution at all (not just in $\mathbb{R}$) because there is no value for $x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $x^{0.5}=-5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real number $x$ for which $x^{0.5} = -5$, because $x^{0.5} \geq 0$ for all $x$ for which the value is defined.

This means that the equation $x^{0.5}=-5$ has no solution in the real numbers.

Comment: why is x^0.5 greater than or equal to zero, is it because of the principal square root convention

Comment: @axcvbk Because of the definition of $a^{0.5}$. $a^{0.5}$ is defined as the positive solution to the equation $x^2=a$.

Comment: so a^0,5 is defined as positive or non existant?

Comment: @axcvbk On the reals, $a^{0.5}$ is defined only for $a\geq 0$.

Comment: @axcvbk Yes, if you are considering only real numbers, $x^{1/2}$ is either positive or nonexistent, for the reasons/definitions discussed in various responses above.

Comment: i am still a bit confused. Is there no solution as the square root has to be positive?

Comment: @axcvbk Precisely. For every $x\in\mathbb R$, the expression $x^{0.5}$ is either undefined or is positive. Therefore, for every $x\in\mathbb R$, $x^{0.5}$ cannot be equal to $-5$

Comment: okay, I understand now, thanks

Comment: Your answer implies that the equation has solutions in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ (which is not true).  Because there is no value for $x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $x^{0.5}=-5$.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw My answer implies no such thing. I don't do "implying" when I speak mathematics.

Comment: @5xum We need to avoid statements that are ambiguous.  Saying “there is no solution in real numbers” is not the same as saying “there is no solution”.  The former statement allows for a nonreal solution, while the latter statement does not.  This is why you should say “there is no solution”.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw I disagree 100%. The statement "there is no solution" is the ambiguous. There are no solution *where*? In $\mathbb R$? In $\mathbb H$? In some other number system I just made up?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw My original answer is only ambiguous if you assume it is trying to imply something. If you instead only look at the truth value of each statement it is stating, then it is perfectly true, in that it is saying $\not\exists x\in\mathbb R: x^{-0.5} = -5$, which is a true statement. Now, sure, there exists a **stronger** statement which is also true, which is $\not\exists x\in\mathbb C: x^{-0.5}=-5$, but...so? If OP is only looking at $\mathbb R$, then the stronger statement will only invite confusion. If they are interested in $\mathbb C$, they can ask more in the comments.

Comment: @5xum I never thought of it that way.  Thanks for the explanation.